# Pager doesn't work

Tags: views, 8, blocks

I have the following view what also is rendered as a block.

[image]

This view has a mini pager with default 3 items to show.

When i check configuration of the block of this view it looks like this :

[image]

I render this block in region 'content' on the frontpage.

When i check this it shows more than 3 items.

How to fix this?

Screenshot of the homepage (Zoomed out, shows 10 items):

[image]

Screenshot pager (Is shown after 10 items instead of 3:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some search on this site i have found the solutions.

The solution is to enable ajax in the advanced views settings of the specific view.